# Daily PPA has been updated, but Linux thinks there is no update

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, ppa

I haven't gotten any updates from a daily PPA in more than a week. But it has been updated and on launchpad there is a newer version (for Linux Mint 19/bionic too).
My package manager thinks, the week-old version is the newest one available.
Apt update says my packages are up to date and I haven't found a solution or even reason why this is happening.
What could I do?

[https://launchpad.net/~openmw/+archive/ubuntu/openmw-daily?field.series_filter=bionic](https://launchpad.net/%7Eopenmw/+archive/ubuntu/openmw-daily?field.series_filter=bionic)

```
Package     Version     Uploaded by
openmw 0.46.0+git202006300504~ubuntu18.04.1     OpenMW (22 hours ago) 

$ apt policy openmw  
openmw:
  Installed: 0.46.0+git202006211445~ubuntu18.04.1
  Candidate: 0.46.0+git202006211445~ubuntu18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.46.0+git202006211445~ubuntu18.04.1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openmw/openmw-daily/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.43.0-3.1~build1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

Edit: what apt update says seems promising

```
 apt update
 [sudo] password for minter:                 
 Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                        
 Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/andreasbutti/xournalpp-master/ubuntu bionic InRelease
 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88,7 kB]      
 Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openmw/openmw-daily/ubuntu bionic InRelease     
 Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]    
 Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease           
 Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74,6 kB]    
 Ign:9 http://packages.linuxmint.com tessa InRelease                            
 Hit:10 http://packages.linuxmint.com tessa Release                             
 Fetched 252 kB in 1s (348 kB/s)                                                
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 10 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

and

```
apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
firefox/tessa 78.0.1+linuxmint1+tricia amd64 [upgradable from: 77.0.1+linuxmint1+tricia]
firefox-locale-en/tessa 78.0.1+linuxmint1+tricia amd64 [upgradable from: 77.0.1+linuxmint1+tricia]
libgnutls30/bionic-updates 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.4 amd64 [upgradable from: 3.5.18-1ubuntu1.3]
libsmbclient/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16]
libwbclient0/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16]
python-samba/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16]
samba-common/bionic-updates,bionic-updates,bionic-security,bionic-security 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17 all [upgradable from: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16]
samba-common-bin/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16]
samba-libs/bionic-updates,bionic-security 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.17 amd64 [upgradable from: 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.16]
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the link to the PPA and the output `apt policy <package>`, otherwise we can only guess ...

Comment: @pLumo alright. But inserting it as code barely works. I have given up formatting it because I've had to start from scratch several times.

Comment: @tobiornottobi that's odd, it is really quite simple to do. I just fixed it for you, but have you looked at the [formatting help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) page?

Comment: Strange, can you also add the output of `apt update` please ?

Comment: @pLumo thanks for the hint. Yes, it says 10 packages can be updated.

Comment: @pLumo but the updated ones don't look like the one causing the problem.

Comment: please add whole `apt update` output

Comment: @pLumo I've done so now. I wonder if there is a way to indent the lines properly without using an external editor.

Comment: not sure, but `http://ppa.launchpad.net/openmw/openmw-daily/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz/Packages` says: `Version: 0.46.0+git202006211445~ubuntu18.04.1` while `.../source/Sources.gz/Sources` says: `Version: 0.46.0+git202007012100~ubuntu18.04.1`. Not sure why, maybe someone with better knowledge of how these files work :-)

Comment: According to [this page of the most recent daily build](https://launchpad.net/~openmw/+archive/ubuntu/openmw-daily/+build/19541644), it appears the the Ubuntu Bionic builds are failing for the `amd64` architecture (and apparently the rest of them).  The daily package has not been updated since 6/22, so I assume builds have been failing since then.

Comment: @GracefulRestart huh, good find. But it said the page I've linked seemed to show more recent packages for Bionic... strange.